# Next.js - Should I use res.status(500) in production since it outputs an error with data in the console?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, next.js

I'm currently working on a Next.js application and I'm wondering if it's safe to use res.status(500) in production. I noticed that when I use it, it outputs an error with data in the console, which I don't want to expose to users.

Is it safe to use res.status(500) in production? If not, what are some alternatives to handle server errors without exposing sensitive information?

I'm using Next.js and I have an API route that handles password change requests. When the user does not exist or the passwords provided don't match, the server returns a 401 Unauthorized response with a message in the body. However, this message is showing up as a red error in the console, which I wasn't expecting. Is it normal to see this in production, or is there a way to hide it from the console?

Comment: Can you use `res.status(500)` followed by something else, like `res.status(500).json({ error: 'failed to load data' })`?

Comment: When the user is updated, res.status(201).json({message: 'user updated'}) doesn't show anything in the console, but res.status(500).json({message: 'error updating user'}) I get a red message like this one [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GcDAm.png) but with PATCH instead of get, I don't want Next.js to show anything in the console.